# incrementing a number till maximum

Tags: javascript, html, function, for-loop, increment

So basically I'm trying to add a page counter to my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>My Text</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.[...] </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <button class="nextP" onclick="nextPage()">Next</button>
        <p>Pages: <a id="pageNum">1/5</a></p>
    </div>
<script src="script/nextPage.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the number instantly updates to 5 instead of incrementing by +1 .

```
var pages = 1;

   function nextPage (){
   for (pages; pages < 5; pages++);
   var x = document.getElementById("pageNum").innerHTML = pages + "/5";

}
```

Comment: remove semicolon

Comment: There is a for loop in your code, at the end of the loop the `pages` variable is `5`. Instead try to increment the `pages` variable by one when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hope it will work for you.

   <script>
        var pages = 1;
       function nextP (){
           if(pages==5){
            pages=5;
            var x = document.getElementById ("pageNum").innerHTML = pages + "/5";
           }
           else{
            pages=pages+1;
            var x = document.getElementById ("pageNum").innerHTML = pages + "/5";
           }

      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Nice! I actually figured it out myself with your template from last time.

Answer (score 1):

Due to *semicolon* `;` just after for-loop statement, your *for-loop doesn't have a block*, remove that semicolon and it should work

```
 for (pages; pages<5; pages++)
   var x = document.getElementById ("pageNum").innerHTML = pages + "/5";
```

Use {} for better readability and prevent issues like this

```
 for (pages; pages<5; pages++)
 {
     var x = document.getElementById ("pageNum").innerHTML = pages + "/5";
 }
```

**Edit**

If you want to increment one by one, then no need of for-loop, just a ternary expression would suffice

```
(pages < 5 ? ++page : 1)
```

function would become

```
function nextP(){
    var x = document.getElementById("pageNum").innerHTML = (pages < 5 ? ++page : 1)  + "/5";
}
```

Comment: it will not work, it is directly putting 4/5 to the page, and not incrementing one by one.

Comment: @ruchikajain got it... thanks for spotting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script code your nextpage button works absolutely fine.

```
<script>
    var pages = 1;
    function nextP (){
        pages=pages+1;
        var x = document.getElementById ("pageNum").innerHTML = pages + "/5";
        if(pages==5){pages=0;}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
However after the counter hits 5/5 and I click "Next"
the counter repeats from 1, but I want it to stop after 5.
Still, I learned something new again thank you for that.